# How to work with csv file inside a folder in usb (Pendrive) using python

Tags: python, pyusb

I do have a **folder** name `csvcontainer` inside a `Pendrive` having two `CSV` files in it
I like to read the data of these two `CSV` files using python I have successfully executed the below code
I have installed `pyusb`

[pyusb documentation](https://github.com/pyusb/pyusb/blob/master/docs/tutorial.rst)

```
import usb.core
import usb.util

dev = usb.core.find(idVendor= 0x0781, idProduct=0x5567)

ep = dev[0].interfaces()[0].endpoints()[0]
i=dev[0].interfaces()[0].bInterfaceNumber
dev.reset()

if dev.is_kernel_driver_active(i):
    print("hello")

# grab the folder if device connected 
#loop it 
# read data of each csv/xls file
```

**Optionally**
It would be more appreciated if anyhow we grab `vendor id` and `product id` programmatically using python

Comment: Why on EARTH are you using `pyusb` to do this?  Your operating system will mount the drive as a normal disk, where you can read the file using `open`.  THAT is the right way to read a file from a USB drive.

Comment: @TimRoberts Exactly my reaction after seeing the code.

Comment: @TimRoberts this is the first time trying to grab a folder from an attached `Pendrive` my task was to build an application that detects `Pendrive` and reads the `CSV` file from it, search in `youtube` where I found few video related with `pyusb`

Comment: Whatever you call it (external drive, USB, thumb drive, pendrive) doesn't change the fact that this library doesn't give file system access, only USB bus information.. You can use `open()` with any absolute path to a mounted volume